# Dynamically ignore fields from HTML5 validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form with 2 submit buttons. The form has several fields and one of them is field "X" with several HTML5 validation attributes (eg: `required, type="email"`). When I submit by button 1, I want to ignore "X" from validation. When I submit by button 2, everything should be processed normally.

Moreover, when submit by button 1, the form is submitted to a new window. Therefore, it's possible that: submit by button 1 -> type in field "X" -> submit by button 2 **in the same window**. So disabling "X" when submit by button 1 is not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pure JavaScript or jQuery for removing the required attribute of button during clicking on the submit #1 button:

```
subOne.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    X.removeAttribute('required');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Volter9/5pxRX/4/

Comment: Submit button 1 post to a new window and the user can continue to work on current window. So this do not work. Thanks!

Comment: May you misunderstand, Volter? Submit button 1 should submit the form to a "_blank" target.

Comment: Here is submit 1 button HTML: `<input type="submit" id="submit1" formtarget="_blank">`. Thanks and sorry if I confused you!

Comment: Remove the last event listener on the form and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/5pxRX/7/

Answer (score 0):

Disable "X" when you are submitting by submit1.
Add success and failure callbacks to submit1 request and enable "X" in those callbacks.
This should solve your problem.

Comment: Submit1 is non-ajax. How to register callbacks for it?